# Return variable from switch function inside another function

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this basic function `getdetails()`, I simplified the code that way its easy to understand what I need. I would like to be able to echo (or use) the value of `title` or `lname` outside of the function `getdetails`. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
function getdetails ($var){
    $title = "Hello World";
    $lname = "John Doe";
    switch ($var)
    {
        case "title":return $title; break;
        case "lastname":return $lname; break;
    }
}

echo "title is: ".$title;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getdetails` returns a value. To get that value, assign it to a variable like so:

```
$title = getdetails('title');
```

Then you can use it as any other variable

```
echo "title is: " . $title;
```